# open source click or mouse tracking software

Tags: php, mouseclick-event

does any one know of or recommend any Click tracking or heat map generation - open source php based software ?

like http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/

Comment: i think this question should be re-opened or moved to another stack exchange because it has value as well as the potential for more good answers as more mouse tracking software emerges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend click heat, because I don't know anything else. Also it perfectly meets all your requirements (open source + PHP).

Comment: thanks. does it support any number of pages ?

Comment: In theory. You can decide wheter you want to track clicks by page url or page title. Just be aware that it's going to create a seperate directory for every distinct page. Personally I wouldn't use the tool on production sites (maybe only for a limited ammout of time), but it's certainly very cool.

Comment: why is that u wouldnt use it production site. since thats where u will actually get live stats. if there is any other way or tool please share it with us.

Comment: I've never seen any similar tool sorry. The thing is, that with every click on your page, it will call a PHP script on the server. Maybe I should've said busy sites instead of production sites, it causes quite some overhead on sites with a lot of concurrent users. If it's a problem, check out the performance tab on their site, someone coded a script which allows you to generate the stats from the log (of a special static site), however dunno if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Well-known solutions are:

- [Click Heat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) (free)
- [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com)
- [Click Density](http://www.clickdensity.co.uk/)