# eye tracking system

Tags: php, jquery, html, eye-tracking

i need to add eye tracking system into a website. something with heatmap, which use to trace where your user click the most.

is there any open source php( jquery, html) plugin to do that?

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [open source click or mouse tracking software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845207/open-source-click-or-mouse-tracking-software)

Comment: i think the algorithm is the most complicated part, mouse tracking is just generate input.

Comment: The most complicated part would be the eye tracking, typically this is done with specialized hardware - although Gazehawk seems to have pulled off the ability to do it with off the shelf hardware. We used to do eye tracking at a firm I used to work with, and it required a special headset and a couple of PhD's working alongside. This was five years ago, so I'm sure its simpler now, but I dont think it has progressed dramatically.

Comment: SO isn't a "do my research for me" website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [CrazyEgg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) or [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/).  Both work well and are easy to implement.

Comment: nice, never even thought about this before

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a combination eye-tracking system / heatmap available online that you can integrate with your site.

You may want to check out www.Gazehawk.com, which is a relatively cheap eye-tracking service. While they've made it more affordable to do it, its pretty much out of your hands - its not a service you integrate with your site.

If all you want is a heatmap based on where people click, you can get something similar to that for free with Google Analytics.